# Is it possible to get the matching string from an SQL query?

Tags: sql

If I have a query to return all matching entries in a DB that have "news" in the searchable column (i.e. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE %news%`), and one particular row has an entry starting with "In recent World news, Somalia was invaded by ...", can I return a specific "chunk" of an SQL entry? Kind of like a teaser, if you will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select substring(column,
                 CHARINDEX ('news',lower(column))-10,
                 20)
FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE %news%
```

basically substring the column starting 10 characters before where the word 'news' is and continuing for 20.

Edit:  You'll need to make sure that 'news' isn't in the first 10 characters and adjust the start position accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use substring function in a SELECT part. Something like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 1,20) FROM table WHERE column LIKE %news%
```

This will return the first 20 characters from column *column*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I ended up loading the whole field into C#, then re-searched the text for the search string, then selected x characters either side.

This will work fine for LIKE, but not full text queries which use FORMS OF INFLECTION because that may match "women" when you search for "woman".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL you can perform all kinds VB-like of substring functions as part of your query.